# Tool to convert multi-document YAML to XML

Tags: xml, kubernetes, yaml

Are there any command-line tools to convert YAML to XML?  I've seen that there are several websites that offer YAML to XML conversions, however none of them seem to support YAML files containing multiple documents and I'd prefer something more command-line since I'd like this conversion to be part of a build process.

The files in question are Kubernetes object files (containing deployments, configmaps, services, etc.).  They are frustrating to work with since any incorrect indentations prevent K8s from loading the file and the YAML parser K8s uses provides extremely vague error messages.  I'd like to convert them to XML for editing and then use an XML converter to convert them back to YAML for applying them to with `kubectl apply -f`.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/tarsil/yaml_to_xml